# Circuitikz american controlled voltage signs

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

[image: Source signs behavior]

Hello, friends. Well, a picture is worth a thousand words. I would like the behavior on the left rather than on the right, the latters are CircuitTikZ defaults. A helpful guy helped me to do it with independent voltage sources,unfortunately I forgot about asking him for these ones. Does anyone have the same concern out there?

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgfscope        \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$-$}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
    \pgfscope       \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
        \pgftext[rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction]{$+$}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/margin=.5}% default too big
\draw (0,0) to[V={v1}] (3,0) to[V={v2}] (3,3) to[V={v3}] (0,3) to[V={v4}] (0,0);
\draw (4,0) to[V={v5}] (6,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

As specific code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill, check out the code.

Comment: You should also update the image to correspond to the give MWE.

Comment: I do not have it because I do not know how to do it, thus far.

Answer (score 2):

1. Eliminating the rotation by setting `rotate=0` yields:

   [image]
2. If you desire the `+`, `-` symbols to be perpendicular to the path you can instead use `rotate=90`:

   [image]
3. As per you comment, if you want the `+` and `-` signs to always be in the normal *non-rotated* position then setting `rotate=-\pgf@circ@direction` (which is what your provided in the MWE above) seems to do just that:

   [image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{vsourceAM}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/width}}{   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgfscope        \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \pgftext[rotate=0]{$-$}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
    \pgfscope       \pgftransformxshift{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/vsourceam/margin}\pgf@circ@res@right}
        \pgftext[rotate=0]{$+$}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/margin=.5}% default too big
\draw (0,0) to[V={v1}] (3,0) to[V={v2}] (3,3) to[V={v3}] (0,3) to[V={v4}] (0,0);
\draw (4,0) to[V={v5}] (6,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, almost there. What I meant was never to rotate the signs in order to make them look always like a “+” an like a “−”.

Comment: @mov0021: I am a bit confused -- your MWE as provided _already_ does that (revised answer to document that option).

Comment: Yes, it works with the independent source, but it does not with the controlled voltage source. @PeterGrill

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler approach by defining one's own control voltage called `myctrv` that modifies the existing control voltage in `circuitikz` (cV).

```
\newcommand{\myctrv}[3] % #1 = name , #2 = rotating of the symbol, 
  #3 = rotation of negative polarity.
{
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[] (#1){};
\draw[thick] (#1) +(14pt,0)-- +(0,14pt)-- +(-14pt,0)-- +(0,-14pt)-- cycle;
\draw[]  (#1) +(6pt,0) node(){\rotatebox{#2}{$+$}}
         (#1) +(-6pt,0) node(){\rotatebox{#3}{$-$}};
\end{scope}
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}  
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\newcommand{\myctrv}[3]  % #1 = name , #2 = rotating of the symbol, 
 #3 = rotation of negative polarity.
{
\begin{scope}[transform shape,rotate=#2]
\draw[] (#1){};
\draw[thick] (#1) +(14pt,0)-- +(0,14pt)-- +(-14pt,0)-- +(0,-14pt)-- cycle;
\draw[]  (#1) +(6pt,0) node(){\rotatebox{#2}{$+$}}
         (#1) +(-6pt,0) node(){\rotatebox{#3}{$-$}};
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}  
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw (0,0) 
to[cV,color=white,name=mycv1,l={v1}] (3,0) 
to[cV,color=white,name=mycv2,l={v2}] (3,3) to[cV,color=white,name=mycv3,l={v3}] (0,3) to[cV,color=white,name=mycv4,l={v4}] (0,0);
\draw (4,0) 
to[cV,color=white,name=mycv5,l=\raisebox{-0.6cm}{\rotatebox{-45}{v5}}] (6,2);
\myctrv{mycv1}{0}{0}
\myctrv{mycv2}{90}{90}
\myctrv{mycv3}{180}{180}
\myctrv{mycv4}{270}{270}
\myctrv{mycv5}{45}{-45}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unbelievable, my friend. Thank you so much. :)