# How to reverse battery polarity in tikz circuits library

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuits

I can't find the way to reverse the polarity of a battery symbol in the [`circuitikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) library! Surely there's a way! Can anybody point in the right direction?

Comment: Certainly there must be a way, but where is your code?

Comment: Well, you could draw it from the opposite direction.  Instead of (A) -- to[battery] -- (B) use (B) -- to[battery] -- (A).

Comment: Several orientations are shown at [Circuitikz american controlled voltage signs]{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212062/circuitikz-american-controlled-voltage-signs}. Does that answer your question.  If not, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 4):

- For reversing, draw the component in the reverse direction, by simply changing source and destination node.
- If there's an info label, change `info` to `info'` or the other way round.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    circuit ee IEC,
    every info/.style = {font = \scriptsize},
    set make contact graphic = var make contact IEC graphic,
  ]
  \node [contact]                              (left contact)    {};
  \node [contact, right = 3cm of left contact] (middle contact)  {};
  \node [contact, right = 3cm of middle contact] (right contact) {};
  \draw (left contact)  to [battery = {info = {battery}}]
        (middle contact);
  \draw (right contact) to [battery = {info' = {reversed battery}}]
        (middle contact);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Battery and reversed battery]

Answer (score 0):

You can use to change battery polarity "invert"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw  (0,0) to [battery1] (3,0);             % without invert
    \draw  (0,-2) to [battery1, invert] (3,-2);   % with invert
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]