# Create custom symbol: diamond / rhombus shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, pgfkeys

I read this little article: http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/bipole.pdf and the other two mentioned in this. I want to create a symbol to use in my papers and projects. In my country, some of them are different from the european or american ones so I decided to make them myself.

I managed to two Romanian circuit symbols as presented here: github.com/PopAdi/circuitikz-romanian-symbols

Now I have to do something similar: instead of a circle, there should be a diamond/rhombus. How can I achieve that? I want them to look like the ones presented here: [Circuitikz american controlled voltage signs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212062/circuitikz-american-controlled-voltage-signs)

In my code, for the one with the circle I have:

```
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\ResUp}}{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0cm}}
```

I managed to make a square with this:

```
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
```

But I really don't know how to rotate that square or to change it with a diamond. Can you help my figure this out?
Thanks!

Edit: my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\ResUp} 
\newlength{\ResRight}

\ctikzset{bipoles/romanianCCS/height/.initial=.60}
\ctikzset{bipoles/romanianCCS/width/.initial=.60}


\pgfcircdeclarebipole{} 
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/romanianCCS/height}}
    {romanianCCS}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/romanianCCS/height}}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/romanianCCS/width}}
    {
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

        \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
        \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\southwest}

        %Desenam cerculetul
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

        %First little arrow
        \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{1.0\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{0.1\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}} 
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\ResRight}{-0.25\ResUp}} 
        \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.1\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}   
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\ResRight}{0.25\ResUp}}  

        %Second arrow
        \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-1.0\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.0\ResRight}{0.25\ResUp}}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgflineto{\pgfpoint{0.0\ResRight}{-0.25\ResUp}}

        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }

\def\romanianCCS#1{\TikzBipolePath{romanianCCS}{#1}}
\tikzset{romanianCCS/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\romanianCCS, l=#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0, 0) 
      to[romanianCCS, l=${j_1 = 4A}$, *-*] (4, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which should give you the following result:

[image]

**I found the solution! I did this:**

```
\pgftransformrotate{-45}
\pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
\pgftransformrotate{45}
```

And it's working great!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What doesn't work with the solution presented on your linked question?

Comment: I added some code to my original post. In the solution presented in that link, they just change the position of some symbols based on the orientation. What I actually want is to define my own symbols, but to use whatever shape I want from the available ones.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: I added the entire code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever want a diamond instead of a rhombus, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}  

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\pgf@circ@Rlen = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
\def\TikzBipolePath#1#2{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\ResUp} 
\newlength{\ResRight}

\ctikzset{bipoles/romanianCCS/height/.initial=.60}
\ctikzset{bipoles/romanianCCS/width/.initial=.60}


\pgfcircdeclarebipole{} 
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/romanianCCS/height}}
    {romanianCCS}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/romanianCCS/height}}
    {\ctikzvalof{bipoles/romanianCCS/width}}
    {
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}

        \pgfextracty{\ResUp}{\northeast}
        \pgfextractx{\ResRight}{\southwest}

        %Desenam cerculetul
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\ResRight}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\ResRight}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathclose

        %First little arrow
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1.0\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.1\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}} 
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\ResRight}{-0.25\ResUp}} 
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.1\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}   
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.3\ResRight}{0.25\ResUp}}  

        %Second arrow
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-1.0\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.0\ResRight}{0.25\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.2\ResRight}{0.0\ResUp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.0\ResRight}{-0.25\ResUp}}

        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }

\def\romanianCCS#1{\TikzBipolePath{romanianCCS}{#1}}
\tikzset{romanianCCS/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\romanianCCS, l=#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0, 0) 
      to[romanianCCS, l=${j_1 = 4A}$, *-*] (4, 0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks!
I was expecting an answer from you, I really appreciate your work. I thought  I can automatically chose whatever shape I want for the symbol. This is a nice implementation too! Thanks again!