# Scaling power supplies and node distance in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I've done some searching but can't quite get (a) components like power supply to scale, and (b) adjust node distance.  Specifically, when I make the power supply smaller, I want the '+' and '-' signs also to scale, which is not happening right now (`power supplies/scale` seems to have no effect). Changing the `node distance` doesn't seem to have any effect either (works only with `of` synatax?).  I also tried using stuff like `<\kilo\ohm>` and it didn't work as expected.

I had asked this query as a comment to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416943/dependent-voltage-source-polarity-changes-depending-on-computer) and posting it as a separate question.  Thanks for all your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{figure}
\ctikzset{
    bipoles/length=1cm,
    power supplies/scale=0.5,  % has no effect
}

{\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt, scale=0.9, node distance=2cm]
% node distance works only with 'of' ?

\draw
    (0,0) -- ++(0,4)
    to [R, l=$10\,\Omega$] ++(2,0)
    to [V, v=$1\,V$, -*] ++(2,0)
    to [R, l_=$10\,\Omega$] ++(0,-2)
    to [V, v_=$2\,V$, invert] ++(0,-1)
    to [short, -*] ++(0,-1)
    ;   
\draw (0,0)
    to [short,-o] (6,0) coordinate (a);
\draw (4,4)
    to [short,-o] (6,4) coordinate (b);
\node[below=1ex] at (6,4) (){$+$};
\node[above=1ex] at (6,0) (){$-$};
\node at( $(a)!0.5!(b) $)(){$V_0$};

\end{circuitikz}
\caption{These are testing times}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As Zarko said, the plus and minus symbols are characters, they have a font setting apart. The class scale do work, but only on the graphic of the symbol, not on the font. About the `<>`  syntax, it is not really advised, but it should work *inside labels and v-i-f*. You do not show an example of it failing, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**
added are more explanation and improved (corected) code in the second example)

- Your document preamble contain error. Instead of

```
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx,color}
```

it should be

```
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

- However, as pointed @Rmano in his comment below, `circuitikz` load `xcolor` package, so you not need to load `color` package again. At this can happen clash between options
- 
- Considering this correction with your `circuitikz`  code I can't reproduce your image (see left image below)
- If you wish to change size of symbols in voltage sources, see if the following `\ctikzset` at begin od scheme helps:

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner  plus={\scriptsize $+$},
          bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\scriptsize $-$}}
```

- Use of `node distance=...` instruction has sence only if  in scheme you have nodes and for their positioning use relative positioning, for example `left=of <node name>` (using `positioning` library syntax) or deprecated `left of=<node name>` without `positioning` library. Since in your scheme doesn't contain  nodes, in your case this option hasn't any sense.
- Your code can be a wee bit simplified (shortened), see MWE below.

  - first example is based on your code in question
  - the second example has increased voltage sources size as well reduced size of `+` and `-` symbols (you may like this changes)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw   (0,0) -- ++(0,4)
    to [R=10<\ohm>]     ++(2,0)
    to [V= 1<V>, -*]    ++(2,0) coordinate (a)
    to [R=10<\ohm>]     ++(0,-2)
    to [V=2<V>, invert, -*] ++(0,-2)
    ;
\draw   (a)   
    to [short,-o]       ++ (2,0) 
    to [open, v^=$V_0$] ++ (0,-4)
    to [short,o-.]       ++ (-6,0) ;   
    \end{circuitikz}
    
\qquad
    \begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\ctikzset{bipoles/vsourceam/inner  plus={\scriptsize $+$},
          bipoles/vsourceam/inner minus={\scriptsize $-$},
          sources/scale=1.2}
\draw   (0,0) -- ++(0,4)
    to [R=10<\ohm>]     ++(2,0)
    to [V= 1<V>, -*]    ++(2,0) coordinate (a)
    to [R=10<\ohm>]     ++(0,-2)
    to [V=2<V>, invert, -*] ++(0,-2)
    ;
\draw   (a)
    to [short,-o]       ++ (2,0)
    to [open, v^=$V_0$] ++ (0,-4)
    to [short,o-.]       ++ (-6,0) ;
    \end{circuitikz}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, and yes, Better *not* to load color at all, tikz will load xcolor and the only effect could be some option clay error...

Comment: @Rmano, in my MWE color is not presented, however, I didn't emphasize this. I will add your coment to answer ASAP. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors and what needs to be done to get what I want. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CSR, you are welcome! BTW, you can upvote answer too ;-)

Comment: Upvoted it, too, with pleasure and gratitude!